When I install 'next-auth@beta' on server, I got [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] Error
I've integrated Next Auth to a Next Js app, which uses apollo client and apollo server along with graphql, I've implemented OAuth with Google using Next Auth v5 that support App Router. On Frontend I'm able to signin, signout and manage session but to get session on server using express middleware I installed 'next-auth@beta' in apollo express server. After Installing this package when I try to run the server it gives following error:
C:\Users\hamzz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:851
            return old(m, filename);
                   ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Hamza the Developer\ChatApp\next-chat\server\node_modules\next-auth\react.js from C:\Hamza the Developer\ChatApp\next-chat\server\api\index.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of react.js in C:\Hamza the Developer\ChatApp\next-chat\server\api\index.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\hamzz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:851:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Hamza the Developer\ChatApp\next-chat\server\api\index.ts:46:17)
    at m._compile (C:\Users\hamzz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:857:29) {     
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I want to get the session on server using express middleware and getSession() from next-auth@beta.
app.use(
"/api/graphql",
//@ts-ignore
cors<cors.CorsRequest>(corsOptions),
json(),
expressMiddleware(server, {
  context: async ({ req }): Promise<IContext> => {
    if (!req.headers.cookie) {
      return { session: null, prisma, pubsub };
    }
    const session = await getSession();

    return {
      session: session as Session,
      pubsub,
      prisma,
    };
  },
})

);

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that the next-auth/react module is an ES module, which is not compatible with the CommonJS module used by the ts-node package.
Instead of using the require() function to import the next-auth/react module, you can use dynamic imports, which are supported in CommonJS modules.

import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"; I'm importing it like this but still it's giving same error

Try this const getSession = dynamic(() => import('next-auth/react').then(mod => mod.getSession));

`import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
app.use(
"/api/graphql",
//@ts-ignore
cors<cors.CorsRequest>(corsOptions),
json(),
expressMiddleware(server, {
context: async (): Promise => {
const session = await getSession();
    return {
      session: session as Session,
      pubsub,
      prisma,
    };
  },
})

);` This is how I'm doing it before. In your above provided single line code from where dynamic is comming?
